# How to check if two paths point to the same folder location Ruby?

Tags: ruby, path, logstash, directory

I have the two folder paths as string. How to check if two paths point to same folder location. I do not want to compare the string as it will not be the proper way. I tried with `File.identical?` but it returns false as it seems to expect two file paths not folder paths as agruments. For your information, I want to use this code in Ruby filter plugin in Logstash

Comment: Just to be clear on the question, can we see an example? Are you comparing absolute vs relative paths? Are you comparing identical paths with different representations, e.g. `./path/to/file` vs `path/to/file`? Are you comparing a file with a symbolic link to the same file? All of the above? Something else?

Comment: I compare two folder locations as full paths, no relative paths and no symbolic links. For example, c:\My\folder and C:\My\folder . If I compare it after doing a downcase, it may be appropriate in Windows. But the same code will not be applicable in Linux also, as paths in Linux are case sensitive, and the two paths compared may be actually two different paths like /My/folder and /My/Folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything improper in comparing strings if they provide precise and correct location. If `File.identical?` doesn't work and `Dir` does't provide similar method, I would just convert the paths with `File.realdirpath()` and compare them.

```
File.realdirpath("first/path/") == File.realdirpath("second/path/")
```

It follows symlinks.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html#method-c-realdirpath

If you are on a Unix-like system and really distrust string comparisons, you can compare inode numbers.

```
File.stat(File.realdirpath("first/path/")).ino == File.stat(File.realdirpath("second/path/")).ino
```

**EDITED**
Didn't notice your comment about being on Windows. I don't know how `File::Stat` exactly works there, but it should be available and using info it provides might be better than string comparison.

Comment: Thanks!. I tested `File.realdirpath()` and it works with Windows as well, as expected.

Comment: One problem with string comparisons is that one path might have a trailing "/" and the other doesn't.

Comment: @Thayne That's why the paths should be processed first. `File.realdirpath("/bin/") == File.realdirpath("/bin")` returns `true`; you just need right strings to compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
 File.realpath(folder_path) == File.realpath(other_folder_path)
```

This method returns string with absolute pathname in the actual filesystem not containing symlinks or dots. 
Unlike `File.realdirpath`, all components of the pathname must exist when this method is called.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated